# Linux forward proxy for client authentication

Tags: ssl, proxy, ssl-certificate

I need to use a simple HTTP forward proxy proxy for Linux to do mutual SSL authentication. 
The proxy needs to attach a client certificate to HTTP request and then upgrade HTTP to HTTPS.

I have tried to do that with Nginx, Apache only to reach a dead end.

https://superuser.com/questions/604352/nginx-as-forward-proxy-for-https?rq=1

http://apache-http-server.18135.x6.nabble.com/How-to-pass-a-Client-Certificate-through-a-Reverse-Proxy-td4754227.html

I tried squid but it's too complicated in installation and configuration.

What should I go for (I don't mind commercial software or free ones)?

Comment: Apache is the easiest one to implement I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to connect first using an insecure protocol and redirect to HTTPS afterwards.

The way this is done using the `apache` web server is quite simple, you can use any of the fields of the client certificate to authenticate your users:

```
Require              ssl-verify-client
SSLRequireSSL
SSLOptions           +FakeBasicAuth +StrictRequire
SSLRequire           %{SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE} >= 256
SSLRequire           %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Awesome Company" \
                 and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "Development" \
                 and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} in {"John Doe", "Jane Doe"}
```

Read the [online documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire) for further guidance.

Comment: I already have a similar configuration to what you suggest inside my reverse proxy. However, I'm trying to do it with a _forward_ proxy, so that the applications inside my DMZ (which use HTTP) can communicate with outside services using a single client certificate.